# Detect Enter/Tab/Up/Down keys in NSTextView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextview

Cocoa noob here. I'm wondering how I can capture the `Enter` and `tab` keys onKeyDown whilst the user is typing in an NSTextView?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to implement the `- (BOOL)textView:(NSTextView *)aTextView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)aSelector` delegate method and look for the `insertNewline:` and `insertTab:` selectors.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(NSTextView *)aTextView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)aSelector
{
    if (aSelector == @selector(insertNewline:)) {
        // Handle the Enter key
        return YES;
    } else if (aSelector == @selector(insertTab:)) {
        // Handle the Tab key
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should handle `keyDown:(NSEvent*)theEvent` message of NSTextView (i.e. write your own descendant).
In this event you will have key code in `[theEvent keyCode]`.

For return there is a constant `kVK_Return`, for tab - `kVK_Tab`, etc.

You should add Carbon framework (and `#import Carbon/Carbon.h`) to access these constants.